# mmap options in malloc

Tags: linux, malloc, mmap

What is the effect of the MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_SHARED options in the mmap? I see that the malloc uses the MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_PRIVATE options for doing mmap for larger memory allocations.

I'm observing that with the MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_PRIVATE, the unmapped memory region is still with the process ( observed through the pmap) whereas with the MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_SHARED, the unmapped is released back immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `MAP_ANONYMOUS`, `MAP_PRIVATE` versus `MAP_SHARED` only makes a difference if the process forks a child that also uses the mapped memory block.

If you use `MAP_PRIVATE`, the mapped memory is marked *copy-on-write*, so changes made by one of the processs will not be seen by the other process.

If you use `MAP_SHARED`, the mapped memory is shared by both processs, so they can see each other's changes.

`malloc()` uses `MAP_PRIVATE` so that the parent and child can continue to use the mapped memory for their heaps without needing to synchronize updates. It behaves just like the data segment that's used for the normal heap.